# Trying to push the value to non-existing field but it won't push using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been trying updateOne, findOneAndUpdate, and update.  Nothing has worked. findOne() operation returns the correct documents.

```
   userProfileModel.updateOne(
          { userEmail },
          {
            $push: {
              userFavLocation: payload,
            },
          },
          (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result);
          }
        );
```

I get this but no change in my document.

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

userEmail and payload have the correct value. When I do findOneAndUpdate, it returns correct document but won't push the value.

This is the Schem for the user profile

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserProfileSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userEmail: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    userProfilePictureUrl: {
      type: String,
    },
    userSignUpDate: {
      type: Date,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    userFirstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userLastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userGender: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userBirthday: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    userCoordinates: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
      },
    },
    userFavFacilities: {
      type: Object,
    },
    userHometown: {
      address: Object,
    },
    userContact: {
      friends: Object,
    },
    userOrganizations: {
      organizations: Object,
    },
    userMessages: {
      type: Object,
    },
    userAlerts: {
      type: Object,
    },
    userRoles: Object,
    userFacilities: Object,
  },

  { collection: 'userprofilemodels' }
);

UserProfileSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
module.exports = UserProfile = mongoose.model(
  'userprofilemodels',
  UserProfileSchema
);
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: I just edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `userFavLocation` field to your schema or mongoose won't perform the update.

```
const UserProfileSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userEmail: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    userFavLocation: [PUT_ARRAY_ITEM_TYPE_HERE],
    
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it would just create the field and add value to it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Mongo shell will add the field like that, but mongoose won't. Yw.